How can I render text at 50% opacity with drawStringWithShadow() in Minecraft 1.7.10?
I am developing an addon mod that introduces some custom swords that keep track of a killstreak.  I want to draw some text on screen that fades out after a few seconds.  I can get the text to disappear after a few seconds but not in a faded out fashion.  Now I am testing the opacity to figure that out first before re-implementing the timer.
I have been playing around with rendering the text at different alphas and I noticed something strange about Minecraft's drawStringWithShadow() function: it doesn't handle alphas properly.  I am rendering the text at 0x80FFFFFF which should make it white at 50% opacity, right?  But for some reason, only a few pixels in the rendered string are faded out.
Here is a screenshot of my problem:
Image of the killstreak HUD with opacity problem
Closeup of previous image
Can someone help me figure out how to render this text at 50% opacity?  This is my code:
private static void renderStreakNum(Minecraft mc, int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
        String streakText = "" + streakNum;
        int textWidth = mc.fontRenderer.getStringWidth(streakText);
        int textX = (screenWidth - textWidth + 400) / 2;
        int textY = (screenHeight - 80) / 2;

        GL11.glPushMatrix();
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        GL11.glScalef(fscale, fscale, fscale);
        mc.fontRenderer.drawStringWithShadow(streakText, textX / fscale, textY / fscale, 0x80FFFFFF);
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
        GL11.glPopMatrix();
    }

I tried entering 0x80FFFFFF as the drawStringWithShadow() color argument and drawString() argument.  Neither worked.  I also tried adjusting the GL11.Color4() arguments to make it display at 50% opacity.  That didn't work either.

Use enableAlpha on the fontRenderer?

When I use mc.fontRenderer.enableAlpha() above the drawStringWithShadow() call, my IDE tells me that "The method enableAlpha() from the type FontRenderer is not visible"

Thanks for trying. I'm afraid this question is beyond me...
